# Why does EnumMap<T>.keySet() return a Set<T>() and not an EnumSet<T>()?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program with a lot of enumerations, and I'm having to return the keyset of an EnumMap a lot. But `EnumMap.keySet()` returns a `Set()`, so in order to get the `EnumSet` I want, I have to use a cast:

```
EnumMap<SomeEnum, Object> myMap = getMap();
EnumSet<SomeEnum> myEnum = (EnumSet<SomeEnum>) myMap.keySet();
```

If I don't cast, the compiler will complain of a type mismatch; it cannot convert from `Set<SomeEnum>` to `EnumSet<SomeEnum>`. It seems unnecessary to have to cast this, as the keys of an EnumMap will always be an enumeration. Does anyone know why the `keySet()` method was constructed this way? I've thought at times it might have something to do with EnumSet being an abstract class, but surely `EnumMap` could just return whatever the factory method of `EnumSet` provides.

Cheers, all!

EDIT: I'm very sorry, the above code throws a `CastClassException`. You could get the EnumSet by using

```
EnumSet<SomeEnum> myEnum = EnumSet.copyOf(myMap.keySet());
```

I really should have checked before posting.

Comment: You get a `Set<SomeEnum>`. What would be the gain to have an `EnumSet<SomeEnum>`?

Comment: @PaulBellora You're right, the above is wrong. I'll correct it. Should be
    `EnumSet<SomeEnum> myEnum = EnumSet.copyOf(myMap.keySet());`

Comment: Also here's a nice view of the source, with inline styled javadoc: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/EnumMap.java#EnumMap.keySet%28%29

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think its because the `keySet` is not an `EnumSet`. ;)

The reason it is not is that the `keySet` is a view onto the underlying map.

```
myMap.keySet().removeAll(keysToRemove); // removes multiple keys.
```

Comment: Conceptually the keySet() is a set of enum or an enum set. If the API were designed differently we could have had an EnumSet interface but given this would be the same as Set, there is no practial advantage.  If EnumSet could give you Enum specific methdos like it's element type at runtime, perhaps it might make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

`EnumSet` is an implementation of `Set` that happens to use an enum to represent the key space. The class `EnumSet` provides no additional non-static methods, so there would be no reason to return an `EnumSet` over just a plain `Set`.

Comment: Best answer so far and simple IMHO. Not refering to implementation details /not relevant to api design) or bad assumption that java doesn't have covariant return types (subclasses can return subclasses of the return value in overriden methods).

Comment: +1 That's better to actually look at the API design than the code underneath.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I was wrong, please ignore.

EnumMap extends AbstractMap, which declares keySet. AbstractMap cannot declare that keySet returns EnumSet, as that is not true for other subclasses of AbstractMap. Hence, its return type is Set.

Comment: Well that is not true, sub classes can have more specific return values. Covariant return types since java 5.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the source of that class then you will better understand the scenerio why it is returning `Set`. You can find that at below url

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/EnumMap.java.html

Hope this can help you.

Enjoy !

Comment: That's really cool, I didn't know I could see the source for this! I've been dealing with the API all along. But yeah, I see that the method keySet() returns the Set keySet, which is defined in the superclass, so I couldn't have it any other way. Thanks a lot, I will enjoy!

Comment: Where in the 800 lines of code in your link would I expect to find the answer to the question? Please post an excerpt of the relevant portion.

Comment: @Gabe If you go through the method defined currectly then you will be able to find the solution. It is not possible for me to post the whole code. Otherwise you will not be able to understand the answer.

Comment: @Gabe you'll notice that starting at line 364 the method Set<K> keySet() is defined. The hyperlink points to [java.util.Map](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Map.java.html), starting at line 298.